# How to run multiprocessing with while loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

Background:

I have 2 script , one for my robot (main_dobot.py ) , one for my GUI (tkinter_oop.py). MY robot script quite heavy which could freeze the GUI, so i try to use multiprocess. First few simple test work really ok. However, when I add while loop in `serial_port_connecting()` function the GUI is freeze.

What i want :

The reason I use while is to let the program run and checking for user input from GUI. For example, the program open with GUI and run at the background. The program keep check for connected command and if the user press connected , the program will find the port and connected to it . If connecting fail or not available , print message "not available".

Question:
Is there a way I could add the while loop to keep the program running without freeze it? I had try for loop , the freeze still appeared.

Extra question :

When I delete the while loop out  of  `serial_port_connecting` and test the result again , I notice the variable self.connected_complete in main_dobot.py could not pass to the `button_connected_clicked` function in tkinter_oop.py. Did this happen because the multiprocess not allow variable to directly pass from one class to another class ?

What I want ( for extra question):
I want the value of main_dobot.dobot_automation.connected_complete (tkinter_oop.py) or known as self.connected_complete (main_dobot.py)  variable could be use in the tkinter GUI , so the GUI could decide which text to shows on the interface.

Error display ( for extra question):
`AttributeError: type object 'dobot_automation' has no attribute 'connected_complete'`

tkinter_oop.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 
import multiprocessing 
import main_dobot 


class graphic(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.reset_clock = 0
        self.check_value = 0 
        self.done = 0
        self.minute = 1 
        self.second = 0   
        
        #button value 
        self.button_connecting_done  =  0
        self.button_home_cablirate_done = 0
        self.button_automation_cablirate_done = 0 
        self.button_quit_done = 0
        self.emergency_stop_done = 0   


        
        self.title('Automation Cleaning Process')
        self.geometry('1100x800+100+100')
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New")
        filemenu.add_command(label="Open")
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save")
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        
        helpmenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index")
        helpmenu.add_command(label="About...")
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Help",menu=helpmenu)

        #self.integer_variable_x_value = tk.IntVar()
        #self.integer_variable_y_value = tk.IntVar()
        #self.integer_variable_z_value = tk.IntVar() 
        #self.integer_variable_r_value = tk.IntVar() 
        #self.integer_variable_x_value.set(0)
        #self.integer_variable_y_value.set(0)
        #self.integer_variable_z_value.set(0)
        #self.integer_variable_r_value.set(0) 
        
        self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self) 
        self.tab_1 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.tab_2 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab_2,text = 'HOME')
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab_1,text = 'Option')
        self.tabControl.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")
        
        self.set_button()
        self.set_photo_gui()
        self.set_text_gui()
       
        self.set_timer_counter_process(self.minute,self.second)
        #self.update_output(200,300,400,500)
        self.config(menu=self.menubar)
        self.dobot_run ()
       




    def dobot_run (self):
       Dobot_run = multiprocessing.Process(target=main_dobot.dobot_automation, args=(self.button_connecting_done,self.button_home_cablirate_done,self.button_automation_cablirate_done,self.emergency_stop_done, self.button_quit_done))
       Dobot_run.start()
       Dobot_run.join()
       


    def set_button(self):
        self.button_home_cablirate = tk.Button (self.tab_1,text = "Home Cabliration", command = self.button_home_cablirate_clicked, width = 50 , height = 5 ) 
        self.button_home_cablirate.place(x=380,y=150)
        self.button_Automation_Process = tk.Button(self.tab_1, text='Automation Process',command=self.button_automation_clicked_clock_counting_down, width = 50 , height = 5)
        self.button_Automation_Process.place(x=380,y=300)
        self.button_Stop = tk.Button(self.tab_1, text='Stop',command=self.button_quit_clicked, width = 50 , height = 5 )
        self.button_Stop.place(x=380,y=450)
        self.button_connected = tk.Button (self.tab_2,text = "Connecting Dobot" , command=self.button_connected_clicked, width=50 , height =5 )
        self.button_connected.place(x=400,y=400)
        self.emergency_button = tk.Button(self, text='Emergency Stop ',command=self.button_emergency_stop, width = 25 , height = 8 )
        self.emergency_button.place(x= 900,y = 50)
        self.slot_1 =  tk.Button(self.tab_2, text='2',command=self.two_slot_selected, width = 20 , height = 4)
        self.slot_1.place(x= 100 ,y = 250 )
        self.slot_2 =  tk.Button(self.tab_2, text='4',command=self.four_slot_selected, width = 20 , height = 4)
        self.slot_2.place(x= 500,y = 250)
        self.slot_3 =  tk.Button(self.tab_2, text='6',command=self.sixth_slot_selected, width = 20 , height = 4)
        self.slot_3.place(x= 850 ,y = 250)
        
        
    def update_button_value(self):
       self.button_connecting_done = main_dobot.dobot_automation.connected_command
       self.after(100)
       

    def button_connected_clicked(self): 
        self.button_connecting_done  = 1 
        self.connecting = tk.Label(self.tab_2,text = "N/A", font=("Inter", 25))
        self.connecting.place(x = 500  , y = 350)
        if  main_dobot.dobot_automation.connected_complete ==  1 :
            self.connecting.config("Connected")
        elif main_dobot.dobot_automation.connected_complete == 2 :
            self.connecting.config("Not Connected")
            
     
     

 

    def button_home_cablirate_clicked(self): 
      print ("button home cablirate click ")
      self.button_home_cablirate_done  = 1
     
     
   
    def button_automation_clicked_clock_counting_down(self):
     self.done = 1 
     self.button_automation_cablirate_done = 1 
     print ("button automation click ")
     

    def button_quit_clicked(self): 
     self.button_quit_done = 1
     print ("button quit click")
     

    def button_emergency_stop (self):
        self.emergency_stop_done  = 1
        print ("button emergency clicked")


    def two_slot_selected (): 
        pass


    def four_slot_selected (): 
        pass

    def sixth_slot_selected () :
        pass


    def set_text_gui(self): 
        #declare label 
        self.choose_clean_slot = tk.Label(self.tab_2,text = "Please choose how many slot avaliable ", font=("Inter", 20))

        self.time_title = tk.Label(self.tab_2, text = "Time Process:", font=("Inter",30))
        self.time_colon= tk.Label(self.tab_2, text = ":", font=("Inter",  30))
        self.min_label= tk.Label(self.tab_2, text = "min", font=("Inter", 30))
        self.second_label=tk.Label(self.tab_2, text = "sec", font=("Inter",30))
        self.label_minute = tk.Label(self.tab_2,font=("Inter",30))
        self.label_second = tk.Label (self.tab_2,font=("Inter",30))
        self.label_minute_zero_add = tk.Label(self.tab_2,font=("Inter",30))
        self.label_second_zero_add = tk.Label(self.tab_2,font=("Inter",30))
        # position label 
        
        self.choose_clean_slot.place(x = 85  , y = 100)


        self.time_title.place(x=85,y=590) 
        self.time_colon.place(x =230,y=650)
        self.min_label.place(x=150,y=650)
        self.second_label.place(x=335,y=650)
        self.label_minute.place(x = 120 , y = 650)
        self.label_second.place(x=  278 , y = 650)
        self.label_minute_zero_add.place(x=  90 ,y=650)
        self.label_second_zero_add.place(x = 250 ,y= 650)
   
    #def update_output(self , input_dobot_x, input_dobot_y, input_dobot_z , input_dobot_r):
        # update x-axis 
        #self.integer_variable_x_value.set(input_dobot_x)
        #self.x_axis_value.config(text=str(self.integer_variable_x_value.get()))
        # update y axis 
        #self.integer_variable_y_value.set(input_dobot_y)
        #self.y_axis_value.config(text=str(self.integer_variable_y_value.get()))
        # update z axis 
        #self.integer_variable_z_value.set(input_dobot_z)
        #self.z_axis_value.config(text=str(self.integer_variable_z_value.get()))
        
        # update r axis
        #self.integer_variable_r_value.set(input_dobot_r)
        #self.r_axis_value.config(text=str(self.integer_variable_r_value.get()))
        
        #update all the variable every 100secs to GUI 
        #self.after(100,self.update)

    def set_timer_counter_process(self,minute,second):
        self.label_minute['text'] = minute
        self.label_second['text'] = second
        check_minute_length = len(str(minute))
        check_second_length = len(str(second))
        if check_minute_length == 1: 
            self.label_minute_zero_add['text'] = 0 
        else: 
            self.label_minute_zero_add['text'] =''

        if check_second_length == 1:
            self.label_second_zero_add['text'] = 0  
        else:
            self.label_second_zero_add['text'] ='' 

        if self.done == 1:      
            if second  > 0 :
                second = second - 1       
            elif second <= 0 :
                if minute > 0:
                    minute  = minute - 1  
                    second  = 60 
                else:
                    self.done = 0
        else:
            minute = 1
            second = 0           
        self.after(1000, self.set_timer_counter_process, minute , second) 


def run_GUI():
    
    User_graphic = graphic()
    User_graphic.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_GUI()
```

main_dobot.py :

```
from serial.tools import list_ports

import pydobot
from pydobot.enums import PTPMode
from pydobot.enums import jogMode

class dobot_automation : 
    def __init__(self,connected_command,home_cablibrate_command,automation_command,emergency_stop_command, quit_command):
        self.connected_complete = 0 
        self.check_loop_after_connected = 0 
        self.usb_check_connection  = 2
        self.connected_command = connected_command 
        try:
           self.serial_port_connecting ()
           while (self.check_loop_after_connected > 1):
                self.home_cabliration(home_cablibrate_command)
                self.cleaning_automation_process(automation_command)
                self.automation_emergency_stop(emergency_stop_command)
                self.quit_automation_program(quit_command)
        except:
            print ("There is error in the program , please stop the program immediately ")
   

    def serial_port_connecting(self):
        while self.usb_check_connection > 1: 
            if self.connected_command == 1:
                self.available_ports = list_ports.comports()
                print(f'available ports: {[x.device for x in self.available_ports]}')
                self.port = self.available_ports[0].device
                if len(self.available_ports) == 0:
                    print('No port avaliable')
                    print ('Please Check Connection')
                    self.connected_complete = 2
                else:
                    self.device = pydobot.Dobot(port=self.port, verbose=True) 
                    self.usb_check_connection = 0 
                    self.check_loop_after_connected = 2 
                    self.connected_command = 0 
                    self.connected_complete = 1 
                    break



    def home_cabliration(self,home_cablibration_command):
        if home_cablibration_command == 1: 
            self.device._set_queued_cmd_clear()
            self.device.set_jog_command( 1, jogMode.BP_DOWN, wait=True)
            self.device.wait(100)
            self.device.set_jog_command( 1, jogMode.IDLE , wait=True)
            self.device.wait(1000)
            self.device.set_home_params(178.9299, 3.3897 , -33.8784 , -82.7707, False)
            self.device.set_home_command (1,False)
            self.device.wait(1000)
            home_cablibration_command = 0 

    def cleaning_automation_process(self,automation_command):
        if automation_command == 1:
            self.device._set_queued_cmd_clear()

            #initial position 
            self.intial_moving_pos()

            #set 1 
            self.set_one_pos_up()
            self.open_grip()

            self.set_one__pos_down()
            #close grip
            self.close_grip() 
            #move up 
            self.set_one_pos_up()

            self.bath_one_pos_1_up()
            self.bath_one_pos_1_down()
            self.open_grip()
            self.bath_one_pos_1_up()
            self.close_grip() 
            self.disable_grip()


            #back to intial pos 
            self.intial_moving_pos()
            self.set_two_pos_up()
            self.open_grip()
            self.set_two_pos_down()
            #close grip
            self.close_grip() 
            #move up 
            self.set_two_pos_up()
            self.bath_one_pos_2_up()
            self.bath_one_pos_2_down()
            self.open_grip()
            self.bath_one_pos_2_up()
            self.close_grip() 
            self.disable_grip()

        
            #back to intial pos 
            self.intial_moving_pos()
            self.bath_one_pos_1_up()
            self.open_grip()
            self.bath_one_pos_1_down()
            self.close_grip() 
            self.bath_one_pos_1_up()
            self.set_one_pos_up()
            self.set_one__pos_down()
            self.open_grip()
            self.set_one_pos_up()
            self.close_grip() 

            self.intial_moving_pos()
            self.bath_one_pos_2_up()
            self.open_grip()
            self.bath_one_pos_2_down()
            self.close_grip() 
            self.bath_one_pos_2_up()
            self.set_two_pos_up()
            self.set_two_pos_down()
            self.open_grip()
            self.set_one_pos_up()
            self.close_grip() 
            (x, y, z, r, j1, j2, j3, j4) = self.device.pose()
            print(f'x:{x} y:{y} z:{z} r:{r} j1:{j1} j2:{j2} j3:{j3} j4:{j4}')
            automation_command = 0 
            

    def quit_automation_program(self,quit_command) : 
        if quit_command == 1 :
            self.usb_check_connection = 2
            self.device.close()
            self.connected_complete = 0 
            quit_command = 0 
    
    def automation_emergency_stop(self,emmergency_command_stop ):
        if emmergency_command_stop == 1:
            self.device._set_queued_cmd_stop_exec()
            emmergency_command_stop = 0



    def intial_moving_pos(self): 
        self.device.move_to( 17.8941 , 6.0331 ,  0.5921 , -134.5598, PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def set_one_pos_up(self):
        self.device.move_to( 62.9159 , 13.689 , -10.0889 , 124.8797 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
  
    def set_one__pos_down(self): 
        self.device.move_to( 62.8941 , 16.9492 , 28.2911 , 124.8797 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def set_two_pos_up (self):
        self.device.move_to( 80.2371 , 6.9371 , -12.9820 , 99.4637 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def set_two_pos_down(self): 
        self.device.move_to( 80.2371 , 6.9371 , 26.238 , 99.4637 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def set_three_pos(self):
        self.device.move_to( 50.82 , -3.56 , -9.18 , -134.5598, PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
        #device.move_to( 52.29 , 31.8271 , 13.82 , -85.6, PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        #device.wait(1000)
    def open_grip(self):  
        self.device.grip(False)
        self.device_setupdevice.wait(1000)
        self.device.suck(False)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def close_grip(self):    
        self.device.grip(True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
        self.device.suck(True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def disable_grip(self): 
        self.device.suck(False)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def bath_one_pos_1_up(self):
        self.device.move_to( 3.1442 , 36.3588 , -14.6246 ,-68.4760  , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)    
    def bath_one_pos_1_down(self):
        self.device.move_to( 3.1442 , 36.3588 , -14.6246 , 89.4437 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
        self.device.move_to( 3.1442 , 36.3588 , 20.5754 , 89.4437 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def bath_one_pos_2_up(self):
        self.device.move_to ( 22.6588 , 46.7398 , -8.1826 , 99.4637 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def bath_one_pos_2_down(self):
        self.device.move_to ( 22.6588 , 46.7398 , -8.1826 , -102.1199 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
        self.device.move_to ( 22.6588 , 46.7398 , 16.3267 , -102.1199 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
```

main_dobot.py ( for extra question):

```
from serial.tools import list_ports

import pydobot
from pydobot.enums import PTPMode
from pydobot.enums import jogMode

class dobot_automation : 
    def __init__(self,connected_command,home_cablibrate_command,automation_command,emergency_stop_command, quit_command):
        self.connected_complete = 0 
        self.check_loop_after_connected = 0 
        self.usb_check_connection  = 2
        self.connected_command = connected_command 
        try:
           self.serial_port_connecting ()
           while (self.check_loop_after_connected > 1):
                self.home_cabliration(home_cablibrate_command)
                self.cleaning_automation_process(automation_command)
                self.automation_emergency_stop(emergency_stop_command)
                self.quit_automation_program(quit_command)
        except:
            print ("There is error in the program , please stop the program immediately ")
   

    def serial_port_connecting(self):
       
        if self.connected_command == 1:
            self.available_ports = list_ports.comports()
            print(f'available ports: {[x.device for x in self.available_ports]}')
            self.port = self.available_ports[0].device
            if len(self.available_ports) == 0:
                print('No port avaliable')
                print ('Please Check Connection')
                self.connected_complete = 2
            else:
                self.device = pydobot.Dobot(port=self.port, verbose=True) 
                self.usb_check_connection = 0 
                self.check_loop_after_connected = 2 
                self.connected_command = 0 
                self.connected_complete = 1 
                  



    def home_cabliration(self,home_cablibration_command):
        if home_cablibration_command == 1: 
            self.device._set_queued_cmd_clear()
            self.device.set_jog_command( 1, jogMode.BP_DOWN, wait=True)
            self.device.wait(100)
            self.device.set_jog_command( 1, jogMode.IDLE , wait=True)
            self.device.wait(1000)
            self.device.set_home_params(178.9299, 3.3897 , -33.8784 , -82.7707, False)
            self.device.set_home_command (1,False)
            self.device.wait(1000)
            home_cablibration_command = 0 

    def cleaning_automation_process(self,automation_command):
        if automation_command == 1:
            self.device._set_queued_cmd_clear()

            #initial position 
            self.intial_moving_pos()

            #set 1 
            self.set_one_pos_up()
            self.open_grip()

            self.set_one__pos_down()
            #close grip
            self.close_grip() 
            #move up 
            self.set_one_pos_up()

            self.bath_one_pos_1_up()
            self.bath_one_pos_1_down()
            self.open_grip()
            self.bath_one_pos_1_up()
            self.close_grip() 
            self.disable_grip()


            #back to intial pos 
            self.intial_moving_pos()
            self.set_two_pos_up()
            self.open_grip()
            self.set_two_pos_down()
            #close grip
            self.close_grip() 
            #move up 
            self.set_two_pos_up()
            self.bath_one_pos_2_up()
            self.bath_one_pos_2_down()
            self.open_grip()
            self.bath_one_pos_2_up()
            self.close_grip() 
            self.disable_grip()

        
            #back to intial pos 
            self.intial_moving_pos()
            self.bath_one_pos_1_up()
            self.open_grip()
            self.bath_one_pos_1_down()
            self.close_grip() 
            self.bath_one_pos_1_up()
            self.set_one_pos_up()
            self.set_one__pos_down()
            self.open_grip()
            self.set_one_pos_up()
            self.close_grip() 

            self.intial_moving_pos()
            self.bath_one_pos_2_up()
            self.open_grip()
            self.bath_one_pos_2_down()
            self.close_grip() 
            self.bath_one_pos_2_up()
            self.set_two_pos_up()
            self.set_two_pos_down()
            self.open_grip()
            self.set_one_pos_up()
            self.close_grip() 
            (x, y, z, r, j1, j2, j3, j4) = self.device.pose()
            print(f'x:{x} y:{y} z:{z} r:{r} j1:{j1} j2:{j2} j3:{j3} j4:{j4}')
            automation_command = 0 
            

    def quit_automation_program(self,quit_command) : 
        if quit_command == 1 :
            self.usb_check_connection = 2
            self.device.close()
            self.connected_complete = 0 
            quit_command = 0 
    
    def automation_emergency_stop(self,emmergency_command_stop ):
        if emmergency_command_stop == 1:
            self.device._set_queued_cmd_stop_exec()
            emmergency_command_stop = 0



    def intial_moving_pos(self): 
        self.device.move_to( 17.8941 , 6.0331 ,  0.5921 , -134.5598, PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def set_one_pos_up(self):
        self.device.move_to( 62.9159 , 13.689 , -10.0889 , 124.8797 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
  
    def set_one__pos_down(self): 
        self.device.move_to( 62.8941 , 16.9492 , 28.2911 , 124.8797 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def set_two_pos_up (self):
        self.device.move_to( 80.2371 , 6.9371 , -12.9820 , 99.4637 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def set_two_pos_down(self): 
        self.device.move_to( 80.2371 , 6.9371 , 26.238 , 99.4637 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def set_three_pos(self):
        self.device.move_to( 50.82 , -3.56 , -9.18 , -134.5598, PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
        #device.move_to( 52.29 , 31.8271 , 13.82 , -85.6, PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        #device.wait(1000)
    def open_grip(self):  
        self.device.grip(False)
        self.device_setupdevice.wait(1000)
        self.device.suck(False)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def close_grip(self):    
        self.device.grip(True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
        self.device.suck(True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def disable_grip(self): 
        self.device.suck(False)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def bath_one_pos_1_up(self):
        self.device.move_to( 3.1442 , 36.3588 , -14.6246 ,-68.4760  , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)    
    def bath_one_pos_1_down(self):
        self.device.move_to( 3.1442 , 36.3588 , -14.6246 , 89.4437 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
        self.device.move_to( 3.1442 , 36.3588 , 20.5754 , 89.4437 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def bath_one_pos_2_up(self):
        self.device.move_to ( 22.6588 , 46.7398 , -8.1826 , 99.4637 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
    def bath_one_pos_2_down(self):
        self.device.move_to ( 22.6588 , 46.7398 , -8.1826 , -102.1199 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
        self.device.move_to ( 22.6588 , 46.7398 , 16.3267 , -102.1199 , PTPMode.MOVJ_ANGLE, wait=True)
        self.device.wait(1000)
```

Comment: Please pare this down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and try to keep your questions to a single question.

Comment: you can try sleep in the while loop and it won't freeze, let say 500ms. on the other hand you will have to use popen subprocess, that will let you communicate with the other process. otherwise you are right communication won't happen through classes.